# What is the equivalent of My.Resources(vb.net) in Python?

Tags: python, .net

I would like to use resources in a python project with Flask and output their names. I know how it works in VB. But I don't have idea what the equivalent of My.Resources.ResourceManager is in Python. Is there same functionality in Python?

I want to save multiple regex paterns like as below.
And also I want to use it in code by name.

Name    Value
Regex1  (?Pnickname\s*.+?)
Regex2  (?Paddress\s*.+?)

Comment: Hello, @Conskie, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Since python developers reading this may well not be familiar with VB or even .NET, it might be useful to provide more details on what type of information `ResourceManager` outputs, and what type of resource information you’re specifically looking for. Also, what libraries have you identified in python, if any, that get close to exposing this data? That might help focus the discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

Essentially, you don't need to worry about resource management in python most of the time because it is done automatically for you. So, to save a regex pattern:

```
import re

# create pattern strings
regex1 = '(?P<nickname>\s*.+?)'
regex2 = '(?P<address>\s*.+?)'

test_string = 'nickname jojo rabbit.'

matches = re.search(regex1, test_string)
```

As you probably noticed, there is nothing special here. Creating and storing these patterns is just like declaring any string or other type of variables.

If you want to save all your patterns more neatly, you can use a dictionary where the names of the patterns are the keys and the pattern strings are the values, like so:

```
import re

regex_dictionary = {'regex1':'(?P<nickname>\s*.+?)'}

# to add another regex pattern:
regex_dictionary['regex2'] = '(?P<address>\s*.+?)'

test_string = 'nickname jojo rabbit.'

# to access and search using a regex pattern:
matches = re.search(regex_dictionary['regex1'], test_string)
```

I hope this makes sense!

---

Read more about python's regex: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp#matchobject

Read more about python's dictionaries: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp

Read more about python's resource management: https://www.drdobbs.com/web-development/resource-management-in-python/184405999

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice! As first step, I will try to create pattern strings and run programming.